# How to test child component event emission, via vitest (unit testing) for Vue3

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs3, vitest

I have a problem with unit testing when I need to test child component's event emission.

To make it simple I will provide a small example:

In EditCategoriesList I have 2 child components:

1. TopNavbar
2. CategoryItems - I want to focus on this one

EditCategoriesList.vue

```
<template>
  <TopNavbar :title="'Categories'">
    <template #left-icons>
      <font-awesome-icon
        icon="fa-solid fa-xmark"
        role="closeBtn"
        @click="closeEditCategoriesList"
      />
    </template>
  </TopNavbar>

  <CategoryItems
    :categories="categoriesStore.categoriesExpenses"
    @choose-category-name="handleChooseCategoryName"
  />
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
import TopNavbar from "@/components/navigation/TopNavbar.vue"
import CategoryItems from "@/components/category/CategoryItems.vue"
import { useCategoriesStore } from "@/stores/categories"

const emit = defineEmits(["toggleEditCategoriesList", "chooseCategoryName"])
const categoriesStore = useCategoriesStore()

const closeEditCategoriesList = () => {
  emit("toggleEditCategoriesList", false)
}

const handleChooseCategoryName = (categoryName: string) => {
  emit("chooseCategoryName", categoryName)
}

So my goal is to test this function:
const handleChooseCategoryName = (categoryName: string) => {
  emit("chooseCategoryName", categoryName)
}
```

So as I understood I had to somehow trigger an event @choose-category-name from CategoryItems, but I don't understand how I can do it.
I've tried many ways, even asking chatGPT but everything that was suggested by it was not working.

---

I already tested CategoryItems so I know that it emits events correctly.
CategoryItems.vue template:

```
<template>
  <div class="category__wrapper">
    <div
      v-for="(category, i) in props.categories"
      :key="i"
      class="category__item"
      data-testId="category__item"
      @click="handler(category.categoryName)"
    >
      <div class="category__item-icon">
        <font-awesome-icon
          class="category__item-icon__item"
          :icon="category.iconName"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="category__item-title">{{ category.categoryName }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
import type { CategoryObject } from "@/stores/categories"

const emit = defineEmits(["chooseCategoryName"])

const props = defineProps({
  categories: {
    type: Array as () => CategoryObject[],
    required: true
  }
})

const handler = (categoryName: string) => {
  emit("chooseCategoryName", categoryName)
}
</script>
```

and also tests for it:
CategoryItems.spec.ts

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/vue"
import CategoryItems from "../../../../src/components/category/CategoryItems.vue"
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event"

const renderCategoryItems = (props = {}) => {
  return render(CategoryItems, {
    props: {
      categories: [
        { iconName: "", categoryName: "" },
        { iconName: "", categoryName: "" }
      ],
      ...props
    },
    global: {
      stubs: {
        FontAwesomeIcon: true
      }
    }
  })
}

describe("CategoryItems", () => {
  it("renders items from categories", () => {
    renderCategoryItems()

    const categories = screen.getAllByTestId("category__item")

    expect(categories).toHaveLength(2)
  })

  describe("when user clicks on the category while editing transaction", () => {
    it("changes category to a new one", async () => {
      const props = {
        categories: [{ iconName: "", categoryName: "category" }]
      }
      const { emitted } = renderCategoryItems(props)

      const category = screen.getByTestId("category__item")

      await userEvent.click(category)

      expect(emitted()).toHaveProperty("chooseCategoryName")
      expect(emitted().chooseCategoryName[0]).toStrictEqual(["category"])
    })
  })
})
```

I'm using Vue3 Composition API, vitest, @testing-library/jest-dom, @testing-library/user-event and @testing-library/vue.

Also if you can suggest documentation where I can read about this problem - it would be great!